# delete duplicate rows that have blob text / mediumtext mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen lots of posts on deleting rows using `sql` commands but i need to filter out rows which have `mediumtext`.  
I keep getting an error `Error Code: 1170. BLOB/TEXT column  used in key specification without a key length` from solution such as:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE foobar ADD UNIQUE (title, SID)
```

My table is simple, i need to check for duplicates in `mytext`, `id` is unique and they are `AUTO_INCREMENT`. 
As a note, the table has about a million rows, and all attempts keep timing out. I would need a solution that performs actions in batches such as `WHERE id>0 AND id<100`
Also I am using `MySQL Workbench` on amazons `RDS`

From a table like this

```
+---+-----+-----+------+-------+
|id |fname|lname|mytext|morevar|
|---|-----|-----|------|-------|
| 1 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 2 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 3 | mar | kam | def  | 789   |
| 4 | kel | smi | ghi  | 456   |
+------------------------------+
```

I would like to end up with a table like this

```
+---+-----+-----+------+-------+
|id |fname|lname|mytext|morevar|
|---|-----|-----|------|-------|
| 1 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 3 | mar | kam | def  | 789   |
| 4 | kel | smi | ghi  | 456   |
+------------------------------+
```

**update** forgot to mention this is on `amazon` `RDS` using `mysql workbench`
my table is very large and i keep getting an error `Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded` from this sql command:

```
DELETE n1 FROM names n1, names n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name
```

Also, if anyone else is having issues with `MySQL workbench` timing out the fix is
`Go to Preferences -> SQL Editor and set to a bigger value this parameter:
DBMS connection read time out (in seconds)`

Comment: what is `medium text` ??

Comment: @dianuj its a text type: http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_data_types.php

Comment: oh you have space b/w that confusing me :)

Comment: Check this answer from a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2630478/1587345

Comment: Basically, create a temporary table.

Comment: @AlejandroColorado this statement didnt work for me,  it did not filter out the duplicates `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bad_temp AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM bad_table`

Comment: @AlejandroColorado also i am getting errors `Error Code: 1064.` and `Error Code: 1241` from `INSERT INTO bad_temp(id,name) SELECT DISTINCT id,name FROM bad_table;`

Comment: Do you want to delete just one of the duplicates?

Comment: @AlejandroColorado yes,  i would like to get rid of rows that have duplicate `mytext` columns, the id's are unique since they are on `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION #1:** Delete all duplicates records leaving one of each (e.g. the one with max(id))

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE id NOT IN
(
   SELECT MAX(id)
   FROM yourTable
   GROUP BY mytext
)
```

You could prefer using min(id).

Depending on the engine used, this won't work and, as it did, give you the `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'yourTable' for update in FROM clause`. Why? Because deleting one record may cause something to happen which made the WHERE condition FALSE, i.e. max(id) changes the value.

In this case, you could try using another subquery as a temporary table:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE id NOT IN
(
    SELECT MAXID FROM
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) as MAXID
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY mytext
    ) as temp_table
)
```

**OPTION #2:** Use a temporary table like in [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_2201621_2/Deleting-Duplicate-Rows-in-a-MySQL-Database.htm) example or:

First, create a temp table with the max ids:

```
   SELECT MAX(id) AS MAXID
   INTO tmpTable
   FROM yourTable
   GROUP BY mytext;
```

Then execute the delete:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE id NOT IN
(
    SELECT MAXID FROM tmpTable
);
```

Comment: from option 1 i get an error `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'yourTable' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Obvously, You must change `yourTable` to the name of **your table**.

Comment: yes,  that is what i did. I just used names consistent with your answer.

Comment: also from option 2,  the example has `(1,'Things Fall Apart'),
(2,'The Famished Road'),
(3,'Thirteen cents'),
(3,'Thirteen cents');` rows with identical `id`'s,  mine have unique id's and all we're looking for is duplicate `mytext` values

Comment: thank you!  the second answer from option1 looks like its working

Comment: the second option gives an `error 1327` - INSERT ... SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

How about this it will delete all the duplicate records from the table

```
 DELETE t1 FROM foobar t1 , foobar t2 WHERE  t1 .mytext= t2.mytext
```

Comment: getting an error: `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @CBroe haha,  yes `CREATE TABLE t1 AS (SELECT * FROM t2);`