# delete duplicate rows from large dB

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services

This is a second post to my original question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350376/delete-duplicate-rows-that-have-blob-text-mediumtext-mysql).

My setup: 
`amazon RDS` using `MySQL Workbench` with connection timeout set to max

I am trying to DELETE duplicate rows from my dB which has close to 1MIL rows.

the table looks like this, mytext is a `mediumtext` blob.  `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT

```
+---+-----+-----+------+-------+
|id |fname|lname|mytext|morevar|
|---|-----|-----|------|-------|
| 1 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 2 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 3 | mar | kam | def  | 789   |
| 4 | kel | smi | ghi  | 456   |
+------------------------------+
```

I would like to end up with a table like this

```
+---+-----+-----+------+-------+
|id |fname|lname|mytext|morevar|
|---|-----|-----|------|-------|
| 1 | joe | min | abc  | 123   |
| 3 | mar | kam | def  | 789   |
| 4 | kel | smi | ghi  | 456   |
+------------------------------+
```

This solution started woking but after about 10,000 rows the process takes longer and eventualy hangs.  
I let this run for over 20 hours, settings at 10 thousand rows with a WHERE condition (i thought deleting in chunks would be safer).
But even with the WHERE clause the system hangs then I have to Reboot `RDS` to access the dB.

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
  WHERE id>40000 
   AND id<=50000
AND id NOT IN
(
        SELECT MAXID FROM
        (
                SELECT MAX(id) as MAXID
                FROM yourTable
                GROUP BY mytext
        ) as temp_table
)
```

heres the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `yourTable` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mytext` mediumtext,
    `morevar` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

**Question** 
Is this sql command ok for handeling large amounts of rows and what I am trying to achieve? Or is there a better solution.  
  
 
How long would it normally take to process 1MIL rows?
 
 
Is there a setting like in `php.ini` inside amazon for large data set manipulation?

Or would it make more sense to create a new table and insert all rows excluding duplicates?

Comment: What indexes do you have on that table?  *(Also, note that your query will delete row 1, not row 2, though I suspect that's not relevant...)*

Comment: Are any of the non-ID fields indexed?  If so, you could loop through those values to delete in chunks. That's not a particularly large table, but I'm not terribly familiar with MySQL

Comment: @GoatCO im not really sure what you mean by `indexed`

Comment: @tq - An index is a RDBMS structure designed to make searched the data simpler.  In your case you only have one index, and that's the `PRIMARY KEY`.  What this means is that the only way to find the `MAX(id)` for a specific `myText` is to check every single row in the whole table.  Which will be exceptionally slow.  I'd recommend checking out how to create an Index and how they're used / relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't use `NOT IN`.

I would ensure that there is an index on `myText, id` and then try this...

```
DELETE
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      id >  40000
  AND id <= 50000
  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM yourTable AS lookup
               WHERE lookup.myText = yourTable.myText
                 AND lookup.id    >  yourTable.id
             )
```

This way you only check the `myText` values that you are potentially deleting.

Where as your sub-query will return `id`s for `myText`s that don't even appear in the range you are checking.

Comment: thank you, will try this.  will this keep 1 copy of the duplicate?

Comment: @tq - I made a typo.  The `>=` should be `>`.  This will delete all rows where another row exists for the same `myText` but with a higher `id`.  Therefor, the row with the highest `id` for any `myText` will *not* be deleted.  Do note, however, that this ***is*** predicated on you creating that index, which itself is going to be slow.

Comment: i seem to be getting an error `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'yourTable' for update in FROM clause`